# MySQL numbering dates per id

Tags: mysql

my question is probably simple to answer (sorry for that) but i cannot find a solution.

I have a table like this:

```
id / date  
1 / 2013-5-5 13:44:12  
1 / 2013-5-5 15:34:19  
1 / 2013-6-5 05:14:07  
2 / 2012-3-4 06:33:33  
2 / 2013-5-5 12:23:10  
3 / 2012-5-7 11:43:17
```

What i want is this:

```
id / date / position  
1 / 2013-5-5 13:44:12 / 1    
1 / 2013-5-5 15:34:19 / 2  
1 / 2013-6-5 05:14:07 / 3   
2 / 2012-3-4 06:33:33 / 1   
2 / 2013-5-5 12:23:10 / 2   
3 / 2012-5-7 11:43:17 / 1
```

So the earliest date per id should get position 1, the second earliest 2 and so on. How can i create the position column in MySQL?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have windowing functions to assign a row number to the data.  But there are a few ways that you can get the result, you could return this position number using a subquery similar to the following:

```
select t.id,
  t.date,
  (select count(*)
   from yourtable r
   where r.id = t.id
     and r.date <= t.date) position
from yourtable t
order by t.id, t.date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4752/5).

You could also implement user defined variables:

```
select id, date, position
from
(
  select t.id,
    t.date,
    @row:=case 
            when @prev=t.id and @pd<= t.date
            then @row else 0 end +1 position,
    @prev:=t.id,
    @pd:=t.date
  from yourtable t
  cross join (select @row:=0, @prev:=0, @pd:=null) c
  order by t.id, t.date
)d
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4752/8)

Answer (score 1):

You could use session variables, but I'm sentimental; I like the slower, old-fashioned method...

```
 SELECT x.*
      , COUNT(*) rank 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.id = x.id 
    AND y.date <= x.date 
  GROUP 
     BY id,date;
```

Comment: Nice this also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Count the amount of rows below each date:

```
UPDATE
    `table`
SET
    position = 
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(1) + 1
        FROM
            `table` t
        WHERE
            t.`date` < `table`.`date`
            AND t.id = table.id
        ORDER BY
            `date`
    )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d089c/5) (only select available, but it's the same)

Comment: position need to have id contraint, otherwhise you are counting "all" dates, but TC requires position within a certain ID group.

Comment: and where is position column in his table?

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan I assume he wants it in his table. `How can i CREATE the position column in MySQL`, not just select it.